# Spawned Enemy Ships Fire Stationary Bullets in the BGE?

Tags: game-engine, objects, logic-bricks

I'm making a prototype game of a scrolling shooter game, but I'm having issues with the bullets that the enemy ships will fire. I've set everything up correctly as far as I know, with objects duplicated and edited from the player ship bullets, to work with the enemy ships.

The game functions as expected, the only thing that does not work, is that the enemy bullets are stationary upon being fired, when they should rather move down the screen.

The empty that fires the bullets is a no collision type (obviously), and the bullets are set to dynamic and ghost, although I've tried setting them to stationary and rigid body as well.

I've also tried tweeking the motion, toggling local values and what not. I'm probably missing something really stupid, but I just can't see it...

The bullets and enemy ships are added with an Edit Object actuator, so they are in another layer like they should.

Enemy Bullet Logic
[image: Enemy Bullet Game Logic]

Enemy Ship Fire Logic (Empty object parented to the enemy ship)
[image: Enemy Ship Fire Logic]
The property sensors detect a random number from the random actuator, so the ships will fire in a semi-random fashion. Again, the bullets DO spawn as I want them to, but they simply does not move.

[image: Bullets moving]
Here you can see the bullets move like they should. The player bullet (Upper) and the enemy bullet (lower). This is the spawn layer where I store the bullets.

[image: In-game]
As you can see here, in-game, the enemy bullets are spawned, but they do not move downwards.

I've tried playing both the main game layer as well as the layer the enemy ships are in. They freeze in both. It's only when I play the layer the bullets are in, that they move like they should.

Comment: From the screenshots it looks like it should be working, check you're adding the right object (ie not adding the graphics mesh)

Comment: *Facepalm* See, I said I was probably missing something stupid, for some reason, I never thought of that... 
Thanks you so much for pointing that out! (Dies inside of shame)

Add it as an answer and I'll mark it as the solution.